# SOCKS4 connection between browser and server fails

Tags: python, sockets, firefox, socks

I am currently working on a python SOCKS4 server. This server works well, though connecting with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to the server works fine. Even other tools work fine with it. As a consequence, wireshark reveals the traffic as expected.

However, connecting with firefox to the server fails. The socks server (listing on port 8080) establishes a connection to the remote website as exspected (here slashdot.org) and the client (here firefox browser), although the browser immediateley sends its FIN/ACK. To illustrate, see the blue line:

[image]

I am not sure, what the missing piece is. Do browser have a special SOCKS4 implementation or what?

**[update]** To clarify what I mean. Consider the following code to check the sockets:

```
  ...
  r, w, e = select.select([remote,client],[],[])   

  for s in r: 
      try: 
          data = s.recv(1024) 
          logger.debug("len(data)=%d" % len(data))
          ...
```

Here would be `len(data)==0` as soon as the browser sends its FIN/ACK, what actually means that the socket gets closed, right? This confuses me, since I have no idea why the browser quits the connection. Any ideas?